# JQ keep key in result

Tags: json, key, jq

I have a json

```
{
    "large": {
        "key1": "one",
        "key2": "two",
        "key3": "three",
        "wanted": {
            "here": "result"
         }
    }
}
```

And I want

```
{
    "wanted": {
               "here": "result"
              }             
}
```

`jq '.large.wanted'` removes the key `wanted`, but im trying to keep it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In brief, since {wanted: .wanted} can be abbreviated to {wanted}:

```
.large | {wanted}
```